# Mysql table definition to store range and corresponding discount

Tags: mysql, database, range

How do I design/create a table in MySQL, to store the purchase range and discount given according to purchase amount?

For example the ranges are as follows:

```
10% for purchase of 0-1000

20% for 1001-2000

30% for 2001-3000

&

40% for 3000+ (anything more than 3000)
```

I could save first 3 ranges as follows, 
but what should be the max value of last range?

```
min      max     discount
-------------------------------
   0     1000    10%
1001     2000    20%
2001     3000    30%
3000+       ?    40%
```

Or any other way?

Comment: `NULL` would do.

Comment: then what could be query to search a value in range ?

Comment: You could use the maximum value for the column definition.